# Log Couchbase Query Results In Nativescript

Tags: couchbase, nativescript, couchbase-lite, nativescript-angular

I'm new to Nativescript and Couchbase, but when executing a query against my Couchbase database I simply want to log the results.  Here is my example code:

```
let rows = this.database.executeQuery('profiles');

  for(let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
     this.profiles.push(rows[i]);
  }
```

When trying to log "rows" using console.log I get the expected [Object object].  I thought I could use console.dir, but when doing that I get:

JS: === dump(): dumping members ===

JS: "rows:  "

JS: === dump(): dumping function and properties names ===

JS: 0: r

JS: 1: o

JS: 2: w

JS: 3: s

JS: 4: :

JS: 5:

JS: 6:

JS: === dump(): finished ===

Is there a way to log the actual results from executeQuery?

Comment: `rows.forEach(row => console.log(JSON.stringify(row)))` or do you want to do it in real time?

Comment: That works perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy to log out the results from the rows array after they have been collected, you could just use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), and enumerate over the array. Which might look something like this:

```
rows.forEach(row => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(row))
})
```